# C++ Observer pattern using templates

Tags: c++, templates, logging, variadic-templates, observer-pattern

I'm designing an observer for a logger class. I started migrating my code to a compile-time approach, and have been struggling with a portion of it that uses the observer design pattern

Here is the original implementation of my subject (registry)

```
class Registry {
public:

    void SubscribeSink(std::shared_ptr<Sink> param_sink) {
        m_sinks.push_back(param_sink);
    }

    void UnsubscribeSink(std::shared_ptr<Sink> param_sink) {
        auto iterator = std::find(m_sinks.begin(), m_sinks.end(), param_sink);
    
        if (iterator != m_sinks.end()) {
            m_sinks.erase(iterator);
        }
    }

    void NotifySink() {
        for (auto sink_iterator : m_sinks) {
            sink_iterator->ProcessRegistry(m_registry_buffer, param_level);
            m_registry_buffer.pop_back();
        }
    }

    void SinkIt(std::string& param_message) {
        m_registry_buffer = param_message;
        this->NotifySink(param_level);
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Sink>> m_sinks;

    std::string m_registry_buffer;
};
```

The Sink is my observer. Now, since I've changed the sink to be declared as a type such as:

Sink<Wrapper1, Wrapper2, Wrapper3, ...>

```
template <typename... Formats>
class ConsoleSink : public Sink<Formats... > {
public:
    template </*sink level*/>
    inline void ProcessRegistry(/*message*/, /*message level*/) {

        ((Formats::template Format</*sink level*/>(/*message*/)), ...);

        if (/*message level*/ == /*sink level*/) {
            std::clog << /*message*/ << std::endl;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
};

template <typename... Formats>
struct ConsoleSinkBuilder {
    template <typename Format>
    inline auto AddConfig() {
        return ConsoleSinkBuilder<Formats..., Format>{};
    }
    inline auto Dispatch() {
        return ConsoleSink<Formats...>{};
    }
};
```

And I call an instance like this:

```
    console_sink.ProcessRegistry</*sink level*/>(/*message*/, /*message level*/);
```

I have tried to implement my Registry using templates, but I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction

```
template <typename... Formats>
class Registry {
public:

    template <typename... Formats>
    void SubscribeSink(std::shared_ptr<Sink<Formats...>> param_sink) {
        m_sinks.push_back(param_sink);
    }

    void UnsubscribeSink(std::shared_ptr<Sink<Formats...>> param_sink) {
        auto iterator = std::find(m_sinks.begin(), m_sinks.end(), param_sink);
    
        if (iterator != m_sinks.end()) {
            m_sinks.erase(iterator);
        }
    }

    template <typename SinkLevel>
    void NotifySink() {
        for (auto sink_iterator : m_sinks) {
            sink_iterator->ProcessRegistry(m_registry_buffer, param_level);
            m_registry_buffer.pop_back();
        }
    }

    template <typename SinkLevel>
    void SinkIt(std::string& param_message) {
        m_registry_buffer = param_message;
        this->NotifySink(param_level);
    }

private:
    template <typename... Formats>
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Sink<Formats...>>> m_sinks;

    std::string m_registry_buffer;
};
```

I'm also trying to make this work in C++11, but a C++14 solution would be good too.

Comment: Are you going to have a separate `Registry` for each set of formats? That's what `template <typename... Formats>class Registry` suggests. It's not clear what `Formats` is supposed to represent; there's no equivalent in the original code you are supposedly trying to adapt.

Comment: Suppose you somehow managed to implement `Registry` just the way you want. Can you show a concrete example of how you plan to use it?